# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass

Tags: android

Guys my apk works on my own phone but I attached it to Google Play Store.I installed app from store but it doesn't work.
When I check developer console I see this error.
Please help me what can I do?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2819) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2988) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1631)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154) at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56) 
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:380) 
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312) at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1086) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2809)
```

Comment: Without knowing what class it can't find (which should be in the log output near this stacktrace) we don't really stand much chance of helping. Also please read the help on asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Might be something to do with your Proguard / Minify configuration, try enabling Proguard / Minify on your debug build, build / install on device from Android Studio and see if you get the same problem.

Comment: @Uncle Soft have you fixed this? I'm getting this exception in Google Play console, but I have no idea  what could be causing it

Answer (score 0):

add this to gradle.build:

```
defaultConfig {
...
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 21
...

// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

And 
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

to `<application />` in AndroidManifest.xml

Source:
 https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Answer (score 0):

Do the steps as mentioned by @Sameer, and follow it up with making sure that your Instant Run is off. 
As of the time I am writing this answer, Instant Run is still not perfect, especially when it comes to Multidexed files.

To switch off Instant Run,

```
(Mac Users)
>> Command + Comma (⌘ + ,)
>> "Build, Execution and Deployment" section
>> Instant Run
>> Disable the checkbox
>> (Window users, you may have to search, probably in the settings section)
```

Now Clean your project and run it.