# ClassNotFoundException at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader

Tags: dalvik, android-multidex, android-5.1.1-lollipop

Did some research on this and found a few posts regarding people facing the same issue in their application. I too am facing this crash in the google console for my app and followed the posts I found ([java.lang.ClassNotFoundException dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463277/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-dalvik-system-basedexclassloader-findclass)) and similar others. All of these suggest to follow steps mentioned on the link, https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html.

Followed all the workarounds mentioned on the page but still getting the same issue. MinSdkVersion for my app is 15 and thus added all workarounds to get rid of this but no luck as of yet.

I am left with the option to change the minimum sdk version to 21 as mentioned int he documentation, but that would affect me big time. *

> I am getting this issue on Android 5.1 and lower versions only.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:563)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication   (ActivityThread.java:4540)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1371)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5268)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:902)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:697)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:511)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:469)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication (Instrumentation.java:980)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:558)
```

Answer (score 0):

Post a lot of research, the below post details this appropriately and concludes hat this is not fixable,
[Unexpected crash in BaseDexClassLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44278561/unexpected-crash-in-basedexclassloader)